# How to screen record using unity app using C# code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to screen record using an unity app. I use this code, but it didn't record anything, but also did not show any error.

How can I record using unity app and script?

I manually run this command on the cmd line and it worked

```
$"-f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p {outputFileName}";
```

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class ScreenRec : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string ffmpegPath = @"C:\Users\Savad-S4\Downloads\ffmpeg-2023-10-12-git-a7663c9604-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe"; // Path to the FFmpeg executable
    public string outputFileName = @"G:\Work\PackageTest\PackageTest\RecVideo.mp4"; // Output video file name
    private Process ffmpegProcess;

    void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            StartRecording();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            print("Error starting recording: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void StartRecording()
    {
        string command = $"-f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p {outputFileName}";

        try
        {
            // Start FFmpeg process
            ffmpegProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = ffmpegPath,
                    Arguments = command,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };

            ffmpegProcess.Start();
            print("Recording started.");
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            print("Error starting FFmpeg process: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void StopRecording()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ffmpegProcess != null && !ffmpegProcess.HasExited)
            {
                ffmpegProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("q"); // Send 'q' to FFmpeg to quit
                ffmpegProcess.WaitForExit();
                ffmpegProcess.Close();
                print("Recording stopped.");
            }
            else
            {
                print("FFmpeg process not running.");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            print("Error stopping FFmpeg process: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        try
        {
            // Make sure to stop the recording process if the GameObject is destroyed
            StopRecording();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            print("Error during OnDestroy: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```